# Lazy load images but abort if they move out of frame again

Tags: javascript

I have a lazy load script I'm using to display PDFs and images.
HTML

```
<img 'lazy' data-src="{{ url_for('get_file', filepath=data['path']) }}">
```

JS

```
   document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
     var lazyloadImages;

     if ("IntersectionObserver" in window) {
       lazyloadImages = document.querySelectorAll(".lazy");
       var imageObserver = new IntersectionObserver(function(entries, observer) {
         entries.forEach(function(entry) {
           if (entry.isIntersecting) {
             var image = entry.target;
             image.src = image.dataset.src;
             image.classList.remove("lazy");
             imageObserver.unobserve(image);
           }
         });
       });

       lazyloadImages.forEach(function(image) {
         imageObserver.observe(image);
       });
     } else {
       var lazyloadThrottleTimeout;
       lazyloadImages = document.querySelectorAll(".lazy");

       function lazyload () {
         if(lazyloadThrottleTimeout) {
           clearTimeout(lazyloadThrottleTimeout);
         }

         lazyloadThrottleTimeout = setTimeout(function() {
           var scrollTop = window.pageYOffset;
           lazyloadImages.forEach(function(img) {
               if(img.offsetTop < (window.innerHeight + scrollTop)) {
                 img.src = img.dataset.src;
                 img.classList.remove('lazy');
               }
           });
           if(lazyloadImages.length == 0) {
             document.removeEventListener("scroll", lazyload);
             window.removeEventListener("resize", lazyload);
             window.removeEventListener("orientationChange", lazyload);
           }
         }, 20);
       }

       document.addEventListener("scroll", lazyload);
       window.addEventListener("resize", lazyload);
       window.addEventListener("orientationChange", lazyload);
     }
   })
```

Flask

```
@app.route('/get_file', methods=["POST", "GET"])
def get_file():
    filepath = request.args.get('filepath')
    dirname, fname = os.path.split(filepath)
    if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(dirname, fname)):
        requested_file = send_from_directory(dirname, fname)
    else:
        requested_file = send_from_directory('./static/images', 'placeholder.jpeg')

    return requested_file
```

As the user scrolls the '.lazy' class is triggered where the javascript then transfers the code from `data-src` to `src` thereby activating the Flask function to fetch the image.

My issue is, that the user may scroll down past like 50 images/pdfs, now theose 50 images will begin loading even if its not what they wanted to view.

Is there a way to cancel the loading of the image if the image goes back out of view?

Comment: Not good UX IMO. If you think about it from a user's perspective, they have just loaded the page and while waiting for the picture to load, they scroll past it, only to come back to it and it is still loading!

Comment: @smac89 I agree, however this is an internal application and that's kind of how we want it to behave, we're returning 10,000 documents at a time for various reasons, lazy loading has made that possible but now when scrolling to a certain section its attempting to load every image scrolled past. Maybe a Timer? If the page doesn't move for 500ms THEN begin the lazy load otherwise it assumes they're scrolling and to not do anything just yet?

Comment: I'd suggest an approach similar to how must scrolling views work, which is to only load the images within the visible view port. Essentially each image will know if it is within a certain bounding box (the viewport) and if it isn't, it should stop loading, otherwise continue to load. The only example I can think of is `RecyclerView` from android, but I'm sure if you search around, there might be something similar for JS

Comment: @smac89 cheers, will look around!